# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__ob__') in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

The error appears when navigating from one page with the ProductCard component to another.
I believe the error comes from the data fetching or the `mounted()`, but I haven't been able to solve it. The ProductCard component is just a visual one with some props. So the error must be here.

Full error:

```
client.js:228 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__ob__')
at VueComponent.Vue.$destroy (vue.runtime.esm.js:4004:18)
at destroy (vue.runtime.esm.js:3175:27)
at invokeDestroyHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6148:59)
at invokeDestroyHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6153:9)
at invokeDestroyHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6153:9)
at invokeDestroyHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6153:9)
at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js:6501:30)
at VueComponent.Vue.$destroy (vue.runtime.esm.js:4010:8)
at destroy (vue.runtime.esm.js:3175:27)
at invokeDestroyHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6148:59)
```

My page `.vue` file template:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <ProductTabs></ProductTabs>

    <div
      v-if="productsLoading"
      class="spinner-border"
      style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem"
      role="status"
    >
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
    <v-container v-else fluid>
      <v-row d-flex justify="center">
        <ProductCard
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product._id"
          :product-title="product.productName"
          :product-price="product.price"
          :product-img1="product.img1"
          :product-img2="product.img2"
        ></ProductCard>
        <br />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </main>
</template>
```

My page `.vue` file script:

```html
<script>
export default {
  path: '/',
  name: 'ProductsPage',
  components: { ProductTabs },
  // variables
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      productsLoading: false,
    }
  },
  // call the get Poducts method
  mounted() {
    this.getAllProducts()
  },
  // get products from api and save into products array
  methods: {
    async getAllProducts() {
      this.productsLoading = true
      try {
        const data = await this.$axios.$get('api/products')
        this.products = data
        this.productsLoading = false
        return this.products
      } catch (err) {
        this.productsLoading = false
        return err
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have never seen `path: '/'` and `components: { ProductTabs }` is not useful. Otherwise, using the `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hooks is probably better in a Nuxt content but nothing wrong here from what I can see so far. More info on the data fetching here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook The error is probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: As you said, the problem did come from somewhere else, it was from the component hover events!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from a component hover event, nothing related to the code snippet above.

Comment: Hello @kissu can you add more description in your answer

Comment: @eli as far as I remember, we solved this offline. This was totally unrelated to the code posted here, hence why I didn't put more details.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, i resolved with keep-alive props on  component:

```
<Nuxt keep-alive/>
```

More info on official doc

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/

[Update]

You can also check if you have on some component:

```
   data() {
     return {

     };
   },
```

Seem it is the main problem

Comment: This is a workaround, not a real solution IMO.

Comment: Your error is correlated about a data() empty declaration

Answer (score 1):

in my case issue was that i was not returning an object from

```
data() {}
```

it should be

```
data() { return {} }
```

at least to be correct. Please check console error related to "data(){} should return an object"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use the created with the async functiion. or better still use the fetch provided by Nuxt.

```
 asynce fetch() {
    this.productsLoading = true
    try {
      const data = await this.$axios.$get('api/products')
      this.products = data
      this.productsLoading = false
      
    } catch (err) {
      this.productsLoading = false
      return err
    }
 },
```

Also i dont think you will need a return in the promise

Comment: Tried your solution,  but the same error appeared.